# Minimum sync time for the CARTO API

Tags: carto, api, real-time

I would like to have (almost) real-time synchronization between CARTO and a data source that is connected through an API (excuse any wrong terminology, I am very new to these things).

In CARTO documentation it says that sync time must be >= 900sec = 15 minutes. Why is that? Is there no way to attain smaller synchronization intervals?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot reduce the minimum sync time for CARTO sync tables. If you want to know the technical reason behind this decision, maybe you can send an email to CARTO support or open a github issue in CARTO Import API.